# How can i execute findBy on many to many relation in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have an entity like below:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Groups.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Group
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Many Groups have Many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

I have related Repositories to those entities.
When there is one to many relationship it is quite easy to get related object because you can easily execute something like:

```
/** @var RelatedEntity $relatedEntity*/
$this->findBy('relatedObject'=>$relatedEntity);
```

When i try to execute it on Entities showed above instead of gathering objects thorough lets say user_group table it try to find user_group column inside user table. It generates error like:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.created_at AS created_at_2, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_3, t0.title AS title_4, t0.text AS text_5 FROM user t0 WHERE user_group.group_id = ?' with params ["8192ed63-5d07-4c99-8902-006a3aa986e7"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_group"

I have no idea how it should be done properly. What have I missed?

Comment: `product_feature` is clearly a table, not column. And it is undefined, as the error report.

Comment: @ihsan Unfortunatelly product_feature has been already created by make:entity symfony command :|

Comment: EDIT: I have changed code snippet from product_feature to user_group because previous one showed oneToMany relation instead of ManyToMany

Comment: show us the code how you build the query using query builder.

Answer (score 2):

In a case of ManyToMany, you can create your function in the repository and user WHERE MEMBER OF, here is an example

```
->andWhere(':activity MEMBER OF t.activities')
->setParameter('activity', $data['activity'])
```

Comment: What "t" stands for in your builder ?

Comment: t is an alias of the mother entity  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')